# How to rename my property value but keep the other infos?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I have an object like this:
[image]

The thing I want to do is to rename the `services.XXX` value but keep his child properties.
For example I want to rename `object.services.cadvisor` with `object.services.new-name`

How can I do that ?

Comment: Copy the object with a new name and delete the old one

Comment: But I don't know how to access to the `services.thisvalue` to modify it, I only know how to get the content of `services.thisvalue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the object to the new property and delete the old one

```js
let myObj = {
  services: {
    cadvisor : {
      name: 'Cadivsor',
      length: 50,
      nestedObject : {
        name: 'Nested'
      }
    },
    other : {}
  }
};

myObj.services['newName'] = myObj.services.cadvisor;
delete myObj.services.cadvisor;
console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following

```
object.services.newName = object.services.cadvisor;
delete object.services.cadvisor
```

Comment: Yes it's the way I need to use but @Weedoze already answered, I upvote your answer. Thank you for the input